# jQuery GoMap adding marker to street view

Tags: jquery, google-maps

First, sorry if it's a silly question but I'm a really big beginner. I tried out jQuery GoMap and it suits my needs. I only have one problem, I'm using the streetViewControl and I can't add a marker to my map. Actually I'm selecting a city name and street address from the database, I thought that was the problem. After that I hardcoded in a value to see whether there is the problem, but still the same thing.

Here is my code:

```
//grab google map location
var city = $('.city').text();
var street = $('.street').text();
var getLocation = city + " " + street;
$("#map").goMap({
  address: getLocation,
  streetViewControl: true,
  zoom: 16,
  maptype: 'roadmap',
  addMarker: true,
  icon: 'http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/Google_Maps_Marker.png',
});
```

Could please someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
icon: 'http://googlemaps[...]Google_Maps_Marker.png',
});
```

The comma after `Marker.png'` is probably part of the problem.

Comment: thank you for the comment, but i dont think thats the problem :) but just in case i tried and still the same result